# What does the dollar sign mean in PHP?

Tags: php, oop

What does the dollar sign mean in PHP?  I have this code:

```
<?php
  class Building {
    public $number_of_floors = 5;
    private $color;

    public function __construct($paint) {
      $this->color = $paint;
    }

    public function describe() {
      printf('This building has %d floors. It is %s in color.', 
        $this->number_of_floors, 
        $this->color
      );
    }
  }

  $bldgA = new Building('red');

  $bldgA->describe();
?>
```

It seems that the `$` indicates a variable like:

```
$number_of_floors
$color
```

But I get confused when I see the following:

```
$bldgA->describe();
$bldgA->number_of_floors;
```

Why are there no dollar signs before these variables?

Comment: Hm, maybe it's time to read the [PHP Language Reference](http://php.net/manual/en/langref.php) again...

Comment: Google and read the basics of PHP OOP.

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php

Comment: `$bldgA = new Building('red');` - Well, yes, `$bldgA` actually is a variable pointing to an object. `$bldgA->number_of_floors;` doesn't call a 'variable', but a property ;)

Comment: @Quasdunk Thanks.  Yeah it's difficult for me to conceptualize that you can have a variable pointing to an object.  All the other times I've seen variables in procedural programming, they had a single finite value like '2' or 'red'.

Comment: In some languages, `2` and `"red"` are objects, too. The "object" metaphor really requires you to think of an object as being a single thing, anyway. Sure, it's a thing that might have different attributes you can access which responds to different methods, but it's essentially a unified whole; that's the whole point.

Comment: @Wooble Thanks Wooble, it'll take some time/practice to sink in!

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You are right, the $ is for variable. But in a class instance, you don't use $ anymore on properties because PHP would interpret and this can cause you an error. For example, if you use

```
$bldgA->$number_of_floors;
```

this will not return the $number_of_floors property of the object but PHP will first look at the value of $number_of_floors, let's say 3 for instance, so the previous line would be

```
$bldgA->3;
```

And that will give you an error

Comment: Good, easy to understand explanation.

Answer (score 6):

`$` is the way to refer to variables in PHP. Variables in PHP are dynamically typed, which means that their type is determined by what's assigned to them. Here's the page about **[variables](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.php)** from the PHP manual.

$a = "This is a string";

$b = 1; // This is an int

$bldgA = new Building('red'); // bldgA is a variable and an object (aka an instance) of class Building.

$bldgA->describe(); // This calls describe(), which is a member function of class Building (remember that $bldgA was declared as being an object of class Building)

$bldgA->number_of_floors; // number_of_floors is a data member of class Building. You can think of it as a variable inside a class, but since it's part of the class with a fixed name, you don't refer to it with `$`.

Answer (score 3):

```
$bldgA = new Building('red');
```

in this case $bldgA is an object.

```
$bldgA->describe();
```

calls the function describe() from the object $bldgA

```
$bldgA->number_of_floors;
```

acces the variable number_of_floors from the object $bldgA

but you should really take a look at [php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that's variable with assigned instance of class to it. And when it object then youre calling/getting arguments like so. Read about OOP in PHP, please. It could be very handy for You and help you understand how it works :)

Comment: Wrong. A class cannot be assigned, only an instance of a class.

Answer (score 0):

The $bldgA is a variable for the class Building

so you can access the class function by using $Building->function_name

example:

```
$foo = $bldgA->describe();
```

the $number_of_floors is a variable inside the class

Comment: $bldgA is not just a variable

Comment: yes sorry i was trying to make it simple to him to understand

Answer (score 0):

`$bldgA->number_of_floors;` Does not call a local variable but a property (it's like a local variable part of the class definition) of a class.

However it is possible to call `$bldgA->$property_name;`where $property_name is a name of the property you want to call. This is called variable variables and something you probably should look into *after* you've grasped OOP basics.

Answer (score -1):

When writing `$bldgA = new Building('red');` you assign the variable `$bldgA` a newly created object of class `Building`. Objects are a possible type of variables.

In general when you see `$` it always refers to variables. `$bldgA->number_of_floors;` should be read as: access the property of the object in variable `$bldgA`